# Creating histograms with specified mean and intervals

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, histograms

I have a set of data that I want to create a histogram for. The thing is, I would like to set the center of the histogram to the mean of the dataset and the intervals to be the standard deviation. How would I go about specifying this in Mathematica?

Just for the sake of it, this is my dataset and all I have in Mathematica so far:

```
Histogram[{0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 100, 120, 130, 130, 140, 140, 150, 150, 160, 170, 200, 220, 240, 350}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
data = {0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 100, 120, 130, 130, 140, 140, 150, 150, 160, 170, 200, 220, 240, 350};
{mean, std} = Through@{Mean, StandardDeviation}@data;
```

You can specify the bin delimiters as an explicit list:

```
bins = {Table[mean + k std, {k , -5/2, 5/2, 1}]};

Histogram[data, bins, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point@{mean, 0}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the form `{xmin,xmax, dx}` for bin specification:

```
bins2 = {mean - 5/2 std, mean + 5/2 std, std};
Histogram[data, bins2, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point@{mean, 0}}]
(* same picture *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this binning function to avoid having to recalculate the mean and standard deviation if the data changes, or manually decide on how many standard deviations to include.

```
binFunction[l_List] := 
 Module[{μ = Mean[l], σ = StandardDeviation[l]}, 
  Mean[l] - σ/2 + σ Range[Floor[Min[(l - μ)/σ]], 
     Ceiling[Max[(l - μ)/σ]]]]
```

Example of usage:

```
data = RandomVariate[StudentTDistribution[Pi], 1000];
Histogram[data, binFunction, Epilog -> {Red, Point[{Mean[data], 0}]}]
```

If you always want the plot to have equal range on either side of the mean, regardless of the distribution shape, use this function instead:

```
binFunctionSymmetric[l_List] := 
 Module[{μ = Mean[l], σ = StandardDeviation[l]}, 
  Mean[l] - σ/2 + σ Range[-#, +#] &@
   Ceiling[Max[Abs[(l - μ)/σ]]]]
```

Comment: I think this solution can be made identical to the first one by just sliding the range in binFunction by σ/2. In fact, I edited the solution to that effect.

Comment: @FACamargo To me it's not clear from the question which alignment is preferred (personally I'd prefer the bin divisions to line up with the standard deviations); but, seeing the accepted answer it looks like you're right, thanks for the edit!